# UIWebView loads htmlString but the image doesn't show

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to use `UIWebView` to load a html string from the web and there are lot of image src within it. The problem is the webview can load the string in the html string but the images just do not show up. Here is part of the html string, is there any problem with it?

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<strong>多年购置户外行装后，在她二舅的怂恿下，终于开始了第一次重装徒步。先来一张照片啊。表现我双脚走天下的决心。此次全程都是手机拍摄，终于感觉到了手机拍摄质量达不到要求的痛苦。同在蓝天下，我们的心情无比跳跃。</strong>
<div style = \"height:4px;\">&nbsp;<div><img 
src=\"http://210.22.129.138:801/link/api/public/media/54d8b2536580f1f2405e79f1\" style=\"height:367px; width:553px\" /> 走天下的双脚！<div style = \"height:4px;\">&nbsp;<div><img 
src=\"http://210.22.129.138:801/link/api/public/media/54d8b2536580f1f2405e79f3\" style=\"height:553px; width:553px\" /> ";
```

I use this to load the html string:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: try this 
<img 
src=\"http://210.22.129.138:801/link/api/public/media/54d8b2536580f1f2405e79f1"

Comment: i tried but it didn't work. Thanks for your tips anyway~

Comment: I've cut the html string to                                                                         NSString *htmlString = @"<img style=\"height:367px; width:553px\" src=\"http://210.22.129.138:801/link/api/public/media/54d8b2536580f1f2405e79f1\">";       but the web view can't load the image anyway.  Is it because webview is limited to display image in html string?

Answer (score 0):

Try copy paste the URL on the device web browser.  And check whether the browser is able to display the image. If the browser is not able to show that image then check the following

1. Check the correctness of the url.
2. Check Firewall settings. (There is a port number specified in the url, so make sure that port number is open in your firewall)
3. Check the IP is accessible.

Comment: the image src is correct and i can open it in the browser. Is there any special required format of html string for uiwebview?

Comment: Can you just try by removing the port number specified with URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use base url :

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://210.22.129.138:801/"]];
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I was wondering if this method could only load local images. After all, web images have to be downloaded before being displayed on the screen.